# How to create a template contains arbitrary amount of some elements?

Tags: php, html, templates

I'd like to create a template to be processed by PHP. During that processing all variables included in the '%' signs will be replaced by the value of the corresponding variable.

```
<h1>%HEADER%</h1>
 <h2>%SECTION_HEADER_1%</h2>
    <p>%SECTION_CONTENTS_1%</p>
 <h2>%SECTION_HEADER_2%</h2>
    <p>%SECTION_CONTENTS_2%</p>
...
```

The problem is that I don't know in advance how many SECTIONs will be.
So in PHP I'd like to create a variables:

```
$header = 'Article title';

$section = array(
  '1' => array(
    'head' => 'Header 1',
    'body' => 'Long text 1' ),
  '2' => array(
    'head' => 'Header 2',
    'body' => 'Long text 2' )
);
```

And the resulting HTML will contain automatically repeated necessary parts.
I can do it if I'll use nested templates:

```
<h1>%HEADER%</h1>
%ARTICLE_BODY%
```

Where `%ARTICLE_BODY%` will represent another template(s).
But this approach looks too complicated.

How can I do it in a right way?

Comment: I'd go with the nested template approach. Because this will be more flexible for future extensions. Another way (but worse in my opinion) would be to first generate the inner part in php and than pass that to you template, but that's basically the same thing.. only worse as it puts hardcoded tags in your php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a fair solution. I'd make a PHP template file instead of HTML. So I will initialize all needed variables in the core file and then make `include` function to use the needed template. So I will be able to do any loops needed within it.